# Facebook "URL signature expired"

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I posted links to Facebook images elsewhere and now I can not see the image.

Example: https://scontent.flis5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/48374097_10156822229099932_7902434783177736192_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_ht=scontent.flis5-1.fna&oh=9c2c411197e0fcbc203d0553ed86865d&oe=5D3B02D4

It says `URL signature expired`

If I try to remove the parameters part, as in https://scontent.flis5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/48374097_10156822229099932_7902434783177736192_n.jpg

, I receive a message `Bad URL timestamp`

Form what I've read, the parameters refer to an hash and an expiration date. Is there a way I can work around it? First thing occurred to me is to generate a fake expiration date and pass it as the corresponding parameter to get to the image, but I did not realize how to generate it.

Comment: You may also get "URL signature mismatch" if you put time in future in &oe= parameter. I think it's near to impossible to guess how &oh= hash was generated using time. As of Nov 2019 Time works for 3 mon ahead, so hash may include anything — quarter of the year, user_id, filename with admixture of cdn hostname or just random junk. Just forget it. Could be this is to prevent hotlinking & legal bypassing their copyright policy.

Comment: What is strange is when I use Facebook on Google Chrome, several images do not load; but most do.  Affects user image thumbnails, images in some posts, and even in some thumbnails of images in my photo album.  And it happens just on one of my computers!  Clearing cache & cookies did not help.